# Broadcasting mulitplication/division with sparse matrix in Octave

Tags: octave, sparse-matrix, elementwise-operations

In Octave, one can do an element-wise multiplication between a full matrix and compatible (broadcastable) vector (*i.e.* MxN .* 1xN or MxN .* Mx1).  But this does not seem to be applicable for sparse matrix.

Consider the following example,

```
v = (1:5)';
s = spdiags(v,0,5,5);   %  simple sparse matrix

s .* v;        % <--- error 'nonconformant arguments (op1 is 5x5, op2 is 5x1)'
full(s) .* v;  % <--- works but defeats sparse matrix
```

In the above **simple** case, with a diagonal sparse matrix, converting to `full` matrix can be avoided by converting `v` to diagonal matrix i.e.

```
s * diag(v);  % <--- returns desired result
diag(v) * s;  % <--- also results desired result
```

but for other cases, *i.e.* non-diagonal sparse matrix, it gets unnecessarily complicated by operand-order.

Is there a trick to doing broadcastable operation with sparse matrix?  ...else is this a bug or feature (*i.e.* necessary)?

Comment: broadcasting simply does not work with sparse matrices. See octave [bug #41441](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?41441)

Comment: I haven't benchmarked, but perhaps the sensible approach here is to perform matrix multiplication and use it to create a sparse matrix again?, e.g. `spdiags( s * v, 0, 5, 5 )` ... ( but I understand you're just making a simple testcase here )